# Subtitles (TRACK tags) for VIDEO tag in HTML5

Tags: html, video, video-subtitles

everybody.
I'm having a problem that moved discussdion in the WEB before, but by now, I can't really find an answer, of better I'm not really understanding the matter.
So, I need to add some subtitlers track to some videos, I'm studying to put in a website.

I know that video are managed in HTML5 form the *VIDEO tag*, and subtitles from the nested *TRACK tag*. Video tracks must be in the WebVTT format.
As a first experience, I created a very simple markup by applying the basic controls, using a video file in .webm format and creating 2 simple traces of subtitles (first in .srt format, then transformed into .vtt), as follows:

```
        <source src="Kayath[1].webm" type="video/webm">
        <track kind="subtitles" src="test_it.vtt" srclang="it" label="italiano" default>
        <track kind="subtitles" src="test_en.vtt" srclang="en" label="english">
      </video>
```

The .VTT tracks file are simple and I think correct. Her a beginning of one of them:

```
1
00:00:02.509 --> 00:00:07.509
Select "Release data download" item

2
00:00:08.045 --> 00:00:10.150
In the data download form
```

Now, I would like to check in local, to process and define subtitle formatting through the possibilities offered by WebVTT (at the moment each formatting code is absent), but the reproduction with Chrome gives me the following error, preventing me from the view of subtitles:

**Unsafe attempt to load URL [...] from frame with URL [...] 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.**

I avoid reporting the URLs because the videos .webm and the .vtt are in the same folder.

A similar behavior is also found in Firefox, where the aforementioned error is not reported in the console, but the vtt tracks also do not appear.

With another browser (Vivaldi, Chrome-based) also an error is showed in console at the page loading, but it's different:

**Text track from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

So, it seems to say that a local works with .vtt files is impossible (but .webm work correctly).
In Stackoverflow, I found some answers, but I'm really surprised that there aren't any way to work locally, just to help with  the VTT formatting definition.
Has anyone a solution, or I really must put files in a local server to test them?

Comment: There are many ways to work locally. You just need a local web server for dev. If you are using vs code, installing the `live server` extension is one of the easiest options

Comment: I really can't understand why load a video file is considered safe and do the same with a subtitles track not...